# What does "Buy British, get Boris" mean?

Tags: endeavour

In *[Endeavour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endeavour_(TV_series))* S05E05, Bagshot and Morse discuss some spying/agents stuff between Britain and Russia during the Cold War (1960s):

> Bagshot: There have been rumours for some time that HMG (Her Majesty's
> Government) has been penetrated to Cabinet level. Maybe even beyond.
>
> Morse: No. I don't believe that.
>
> Bagshot: You may not, but our friends on the Continent seriously think so. Why do you think de Gaulle is so determined to keep us out of the European Community? **Buy British, get Boris.**

Who is this "**Boris**" here and what does "**Buy British, get Boris**" mean in this context?

Comment: My first thought when I read the title was [Boris Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Johnson).

Comment: @F1Krazy Well, now I'm afraid of buying Terry's Chocolate Orange.

Comment: No longer made in Britain - so you are safe.

Comment: Whereas I thought of [Boris the Bullet Dodger](https://snatch.fandom.com/wiki/Boris_The_Blade)...

Comment: ... they were determined to get ***into*** the European Community? How the tables have turned.

Comment: should that be "keep us *out* of the European Community"?

Comment: @user253751 The EU isn't the European community, no matter how hard some people try to make you think that.

Comment: @Luaan The EU is its legal successor, so the joke is perfectly valid in my eyes

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Boris has commonly been used to mean "Russian/Communist" in English / US slang, at least during the Cold War period.

Thus the phrase "Buy British, get Boris" implies that remaining British centered was playing into the hands of the communist-infiltrated UK government.

Comment: similar as Uncle Joe?

Comment: Yep, Uncle Joe referred to Stalin specifically

Comment: "Buy British" is also a well-used slogan with many google hits for posters in the 1960s.

Comment: @Rahn: It’s a bit different from “Uncle Joe”.  As Paule_D says, that refers to Josef Stalin specifically. The name *Boris*, by contrast, isn’t associated with any single individual, but with Russians in general.  *Klaus* has been used to refer to a generic German, in a similary often-slightly-derogatory way.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I would've thought it was referring to [Boris Godunov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Godunov).  Or failing that, maybe [Boris Badenov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Badenov), who would be a familiar character in the 1960's...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I don't think it's with respect to a specific example - it's just a generic Russian name.  Similarly _Ivan_ is another generic name - hence the 'Crazy Ivan' in the _Hunt for Red October_ is a Russian submarine doing a crazy manoeuvre.

Comment: Does the "get" here mean something like hire Russians (as in "get him to do this work") or does it mean to become more Russian (as in "he is getting more annoyed")?

Comment: Imply, not infer.

Comment: @Acccumulation Yep, thanks for the correcttion

Comment: @user13267 No, "get" means more along the lines of "_and you will end up with_". Buy British and you will end up with Russians (or those under Russian influence) in power.

Answer (score 5):

Many common names have been used as **derogatory** terms for specific ethnicities, nationalities, countries, personality types, etc. They may originate from a predominantly used actual name. Or, they could originate from a famous or dominant person from the indicated culture. Many of these are used regionally. Some of these are so widespread that they are almost universal. Most must be taken in context to make sense. For the most part, their usage would be considered rude at best. Boris is such a derogatory term meant to indicate communist Russia.